# Spivak, Ch. 26 "Complex Functions": Understanding proof that it is impossible to find continuous $f$ such that $(f(z))^2=z$ for all $z$.

Tags: calculus, complex-numbers, proof-explanation

Consider the problem of defining a "square-root function" for complex numbers, that is, a function $f$ such that $(f(z))^2=z$ for all $z$.

Note that every complex number except zero has two square roots. For $z\in\mathbb{C}$, which one of the two should be chosen as the square root of $z$?

> There is no clear criterion for selecting one root to be $f(z)$, in
> preference to another.
>
> One way to define $f$ is the following. We set $f(0)=0$, and for
> $z\neq 0$ we set
>
> $$f(z)=\sqrt{|z|}\left ( \cos{\frac{\theta(z)}{2}}+
>  i\sin{\frac{\theta(z)}{2}}\right )\tag{1}$$
>
> where $\theta(z)$ is the argument function for complex $z$.
>
> Since $f(z)^2= |z|(\cos{\theta(z)}+i\sin{\theta(z)})=z$, we see that
> $f(z)$ is a square root of $z$. But since [$\theta$ is
> discontinuous](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4589067/spivak-understanding-discontinuity-of-the-argument-function-defined-on-complex?noredirect=1#comment9662757_4589067), $f$ is also discontinuous.

At this point two claims are made by Spivak

> As a matter of fact, it is impossible to find a continuous $f$ such
> that $(f(z))^2=z$ for all $z$. In fact, it is even impossible for
> $f(z)$ to be defined for all $z$ with $|z|=1$.

He goes on

> To prove this by contradiction, we can assume that $f(1)=1$ (since we
> could always replace $f$ by $-f$).

Here is the rest of the proof exactly as it appears in Spivak.

> Then we claim that for all $\theta$ with $0\leq\theta <2\pi$ we have
>
> $$f(\cos{\theta}+i\sin{\theta})=\cos{\frac{\theta}{2}}+i\sin{\frac{\theta}{2}}\tag{*}$$
>
> The argument for this is left to you (it is a standard type of least
> upper bound argument). But (*) implies that
>
> $$\lim\limits_{\theta\to 2\pi} f(\cos{\theta}+i\sin{\theta}) =
>  \cos{\pi}+i\sin{\pi}$$
>
> $$=-1$$
>
> $$\neq f(1)$$
>
> even though $\cos{\theta}+i\sin{\theta} \to 1$ as $\theta\to 2\pi$.
> Thus we have our contradiction.

It is not clear to me exactly what the assumptions were and what was proved.

It seems that the assumptions were

- $f$ is continuous at $1$
- $f(1)=1$
- $|z|=1$

The contradiction seems to be with the first assumption, correct?

What of the claim that $f(z)$ can't be defined for all $z$ with $|z|=1$?

Also, what is the "least upper bound argument" mentioned?

Comment: Spivak is claiming that $\sqrt{z}$ can not be Continuous on the Complex Plane. Then the Special Case is considered , where $\sqrt{z}$ is defined on the Unit Circle. Even there , it is not Continuous. The Proof has the assumptions you listed + 1 more , that is $\sqrt{z}=f(z)$ on the Unit Circle. The Derivation is that , in the limit , $f(1)=-1$ which , taken with $f(1)=+1$ , will give the Contradiction. It shows that $f(1)$ can not be Defined Consistently AND Continuously !

Comment: I just want to confirm if you were precise with your last few comments. You wrote "The derivation is that, in the limit, $f(1)=-1$, which, taken with $f(1)=1$...", but that last part should read "taken with $\lim\limits_{z\to 2\pi} f(z)=1$ gives the contradiction", right? Not sure what defined "consistently" means. But I can see that it cannot be defined continuously at $1$.

Comment: Also, what is the least upper bound argument he mentioned?

Comment: Also, I guess he used $f(1)=\pm 1$ because he is considering the $f$ in (1). But the claim to be proved is apparently speaking of a general function $f$. How does this proof which uses this specific $f$ generalize to the claim that we can't find any $f$  that is continuous and also the square root function.

Comment: Your Comment about the limit : Yes , that is what I meant about "in the limit". It cannot be continuous at 1 : We may hypothetically "twist" the function to have same value & same limit , in which case it will be **Continuous but not Consistent** with the meaning of square root.

Comment: Your Comment about "least upper bound" : Spivak claims that the square root function must be of the type given , he is asking the reader to Prove it using such arguments. You might have to refer back to that text book on what has been proved till that Point & how he has used such arguments till that Point. It is very straight forward using https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler's_formula , but we have to see what that text book is using & what has been Proved till that Point.

Comment: Your Comment about the "general function" : Yes , he has Proved it for the Unit Circle & not Proved it for the Whole Plane , but the Unit Circle is Part of the Whole Plane ! If there were some function which was Continuous on the Whole Plane , then it must be Continuous on the Unit Circle too , which we showed is not Possible. Hence , that is not Possible on the Whole Plane !